# Spacing between clouds

Tags: python, matplotlib

### Example 1

[image]

### Example 2

[image]

On both picture, we can clearly distinguish two distinct clouds.

Here is the part of the code which produce these two images :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d') 

#ax.set_xlabel('PC 1', fontsize = 15)
#ax.set_ylabel('PC 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_xlim3d([-10, 10])
ax.set_ylim3d([-10, 10])
ax.set_zlim3d([-10, 10])
ax.set_title('2 Component PCA', fontsize = 20)

targets = [1, 0]
colors = ['r', 'g']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDf['Label_Capture_Spread'] == target
    ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'PC 1'],
               finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'PC 2'],
               finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'PC 3'],
               c = color,
               s = 20)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

On both images, there's no space between both clouds. Is there a way to separate both clouds from each other? Can we put the dots in a bubble to make a clear distinction of each cloud?

Comment: Isn't this about shifting the angle of the 3d plot and scaling the plot?

Comment: I got something similar in rotating the plot. I would like a tool to separate both clouds or just put inside a bubble. So it can be a red bubble for red dots and blue bubble for blue dots.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what would help is trying to figure out the convex hull from the points and plot the shape along with points (or without them). A sketch of the solution for 2d you can find in the question [Plotting a set of given points to form a closed curve in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763853/plotting-a-set-of-given-points-to-form-a-closed-curve-in-matplotlib).

Comment: Can you give me an example how to modify my current code?