# Plotting a connected scatter plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns and around 50 rows. I want to create a scatter plot of the two columns but I also want to have the datapoints connected to each other. So I did something like this:

```
plt.plot(df['colA'], df['colB'], 'o-')
plt.show()
```

I am getting an output like this:
[image]

But I want to have data points connected to each other so as to give an ellipse circumscribing the data points. I feel like the reason I'm getting this plot is that in the *dataframe* that's how the datapoints are sequenced. 
Is there a way to deal with this?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you'd need to sort them into the correct order.  You could do this by creating another column corresponding to the angle around the circle.  To calculate this, pick a point, `(xc, yc)`, that's within the circle (say the vector average of all the points) , and then `A = atan2(y-yc, x-xc)`, and order by column A.

Comment: Use `ConvexHull` to get this done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763853/plotting-a-set-of-given-points-to-form-a-closed-curve-in-matplotlib