# How to draw a border around datapoints of the same cluster in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I wonder if there is a way to draw a border around data points of the same cluster (same label) in a scatter plot, using Matplotlib? I mean borders, like in the attached image.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The keyword I was searching for was **Convex Hulls**. Scipy offers a class that can easily calculate the Convex Hull of a list of data points.

The code in this post was quite helpful: [Plotting a set of given points to form a closed curve in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763853/plotting-a-set-of-given-points-to-form-a-closed-curve-in-matplotlib)